# How to insert images as per slide title through vba code

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I want to write VBA code for inserting the image as per the slide name from the folder means after running the VBA it automatically inserts the images as per the slide name

For eg: if the slide contains "Top View" in the text box then by running the VBA script it should automatically pick the picture having name "Top View" from the particular folder.
As shown in the attached images.

[Slide having by text box as top view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voAUs.png)

[Folder Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qgRo.png)

I have posted one of the question some days ago but I didn't find the exact solution here is the link of my previous question which I have asked

[Previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67904908/how-to-write-vba-code-for-inserting-images-as-per-slide-title)

One of member has shared one code but its working properly also I modified it little bit though its not working properly if possible pl. help me

```
Option Explicit

Sub image_insert()

Dim objPresentaion As Presentation
Dim objSlide As Slide
Dim objImageBox As Shape
Dim sSlideTitle As String
Dim sFolder As String

Set objPresentaion = ActivePresentation
sFolder = "C:\Users\mehta\Desktop\Folder for ppt images\Top 
View.jpg"


For Each objSlide In objPresentaion.Slides
    sSlideTitle = GetTitleText(objSlide)
    ' WAS there a title on the slide?
    If Len(sSlideTitle) > 0 Then
        ' make sure the image exists
        If Len(Dir$(sFolder & sSlideTitle & ".JPG")) > 0 Then
            Set objImageBox = objSlide.Shapes.AddPicture(sFolder & 
sSlideTitle & ".JPG", _
            msoCTrue, msoCTrue, 25, 25)
        Else
           ' Comment this out later
           ' MsgBox "Image missing: " & sSlideTitle
        End If
    Else
        ' comment this out later:
        MsgBox "This slide has no title"
    End If

Next    ' Slide

End Sub

Function GetTitleText(oSl As Slide) As String

Dim sTemp As String

With oSl
    ' handle errors in case there's no slide title
    On Error Resume Next
    sTemp = .Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        sTemp = ""
    End If
End With

GetTitleText = sTemp

End Function
```

Regards.

Comment: Please edit your question so that all the relevant details are in *this* post.

Comment: Ok sure @Toddleson i will update it soon thank you....

Comment: Hi @Toddleson I Have kept my earlier same post link in the question for the reference while i have again re explained my goal hope i can get solution

Comment: >> One of member has shared one code but its working properly also I modified it little bit though its not working properly <<  A) How did you modify it?  B) What does "not working properly" mean?

Comment: @SteveRindsberg pl. have a look at below code

Comment: Sub image_insert()
Dim objPresentaion As Presentation
Dim objSlide As Slide
Dim objImageBox As Shape
Dim sFolder As String
Dim mytitle As Variant
Set objPresentaion = ActivePresentation
sFolder = "C:\Users\mehta\Desktop\Folder for ppt images\TopView.JPG"
mytitle = mydocument.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
For Each objSlide In objPresentaion.Slides
If Len(mytitle) > 0 Then
If Len(Dir$(sFolder & mytitle & ".JPG")) > 0 Then Set objImageBox = objSlide.Shapes.AddPicture(sFolder & mytitle & ".JPG", msoCTrue, msoCTrue, 25, 25)
End If
End If
Next  
End Sub'

Comment: You've set sFolder to "C:\Users\mehta\Desktop\Folder for ppt images\TopView.JPG" so if you have a slide titled MYTITLE, your code is looking for C:\Users\mehta\Desktop\Folder for ppt images\TopView.JPGMYTITLE.JPG  Try setting sFolder to "C:\Users\mehta\Desktop\Folder for ppt images\" instead.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg I have changed the folder path as you mentioned in the comment then also it's not working....:(

Comment: @ShubhamMehta It's difficult to read code that's been pasted into a comment as you've done here. Please edit your original question, paste your code in there and format it properly. Also, please ANSWER the questions people have asked; you still haven't told us what "not working properly" means.  I've had another look and noticed that you haven't defined or set a reference to mydocument.  That alone prevents your code from even compiling.